# couldn't install Debian on MacBook Pro 2013

Tags: debian, macos, macintosh

I'm trying to install Debian on my MacBook Pro (late 2013):

1. prepare a bootable usb: `$ sudo dd if=path_to/debian-live-12.0.0-amd64-xfce.iso of=/dev/sda`
2. plug in usb drive and reboot MacBook:

[image]

The installer is loaded then it just reboot after a few seconds (before I did anthing). I try several times rebooting into installation page but it still reboot after clicking "start installer".

Did I trigger some protection mechanism? If so, how do I turn them off to install Linux on it?

---

update:

- I am unable to enter live system safe mode. Once clicking, another reboot triggered.
- The bootable usd drive works on my ThinkPad, that I enter installater successfully.
- I have also tried burnning the iso with `$ cp debian.iso /dev/sdX; sync` but still couldn't start the installer (nothing different happens).